# Drag an drop with array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

I have two arrays of objects, an A and a B.

I have a kind of list of each one and I intend to drag the objects from A to B and from B to A.

My problem is that when I drag all objects from A to B or from B to A, when trying to pass an object to the empty list, it stops working.

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the box-list get empty the height will be 0px of the div where the event is attached:

The solution is to add a height property with 100% :

```
style="height:100%"
```

Try this :

```
<div class="six" style=" height: 75%;">
  <div class="card-deck cardsZone">
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;"  #activeList="cdkDropList"
      class="box-list" style="height:100%"
      cdkDropList
      cdkDropListOrientation="vertical"
      [cdkDropListData]="A"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[inactiveList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let nw of A" cdkDrag>
        <div class="card mysmallCcards">             
          <div class="card-body">
                   <span>{{nw.name}}</span>         
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;" #inactiveList="cdkDropList"
      class="box-list" style="height:100%"
      cdkDropList
      cdkDropListOrientation="vertical"
      [cdkDropListData]="B"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[activeList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let pr of B" cdkDrag>
        <div class="card mysmallCcards">
          <div class="card-body">
           <span>{{pr.name}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```